# Module: Extend "Authoring information"-tab and adding new field to it

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm looking for a way to attach a custom field of my module to "Authoring information"-tab.

Thanks for any hint

Answer (score 2):

Use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), add your form item to `$form['author']` fieldset (see [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7) function), add your own submit function to `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']` array (or `$form['#submit']`) and you're good to go! And always remember, [Form API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) is one of your best friends!

Comment: But how can I save that value? Thanks for the answer!